# How to trigger a step manually with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

In every CI solution (Jenkins, CircleCI, GitlabCI), it's possible to pause a pipeline and wait to a manual approval to continue.

How to do this with GitHub Actions?

Comment: Possible workaround: trigger a run via a comment maybe? https://github.community/t/trigger-a-github-workflow-if-it-matches-a-particular-comment-in-the-pull-request/116402

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems you can do this now using Environments: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments

Simply create an environment, select required reviewers, add yourself or a team, and then hit save.

Then associate the environment in your Github Actions YAML file like so

```
environment:
  name: <Your Github Environment here>
```

Then to release that step you can click "Review Deployments" and then choose which environment you want to deploy.

Comment: Note that for private repos, this feature is only available when using Github Enterprise

Answer (score 8):

There is still no dedicated feature to do that very simple and needed task. I have a workaround though.

- If you are not using environments just define one, call it "manual_approval" or something similar and assign required approver (can be groups). That will do the trick.
- If you are already using environments just define 2 environment entries for each (e.g. "prod" & "prod-manual"). Then configure them the same way just adding the required approver on the manual one.

  You now just have to add this environment in your pipeline as in this example:

  ```
    name: manual approval demo
    on:
      push:

    jobs:
      tf_plan:
        name: Terraform Plan
        runs-on: terraform
        environment: Prod
        steps:
        ...

      tf_apply:
        name: Terraform Apply
        runs-on: terraform
        environment: Prod-manual
        steps:
        ...
  ```

  You have to define 2 environments per real life environment as the workflow can reference only a single environment per job.

Comment: For others finding this: the documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-environments-to-manually-trigger-workflow-jobs

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do it now (not sure when this started being available, but I just saw it). So basically just add "workflow_dispatch:" before your workflow like this

```
  # Controls when the workflow will run 
  on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
    push:
      branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
    workflow_dispatch:

  # A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
  jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
    build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

And now when you navigate to "Actions" tab and select the workflow you added this command to, you see a "Run workflow" dropdown above the list. Use this control to manually run your workflow.

[Here is where you should see the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaSv8.png)

Comment: That's not exactly my question, yes it's possible to trigger a pipeline(or a job) but not a single step.

Comment: @Antoine my bad.... This popped when i was looking for "how to manually trigger..", so I overlooked

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no manual triggering at the moment. You can only re-run failed workflows.

But there are lots of useful events to achieve similar things.

E.g.: the [Label event](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#label-event-label): Someone puts the "Approved" label on a PR.

Or the [Pull request review comment event](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull-request-review-comment-event-pull_request_review_comment): Someone comments "Deploy to stage." on a PR.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a simple step in your workflow, that does nothing but echo something - and set an environment on that step with required reviewers.

Like here, where I have made a "ManualApprove" step that is required to succeed before my Plan step runs through. The "approvers" environment contains nothing but the required reviewers.

```
ManualApprove:
needs: TerraformShow
environment:
  name: approvers
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: manual approve
  run: |
      echo "Manually approved"
```

[image: Workflow]

This will give you a button you can click, like you know it from GitLab etc...

Comment: You dont need the separate job that does nothing but echo, the environment can be set on the job that needs to be approved before running

Answer (score 0):

There is no manual trigger at the moment, however, Github provides on_dispatch event which you can target to initiate a re-run. You can do this via curl or also from within Postman. I have written up a solution with Postman and included screenshots here: 
https://medium.com/@christinavhastenrath/how-to-run-github-actions-manually-afebbe77d325

Github also just released their GitHub Actions API, which can be used to build triggers. You can find the API docs here: https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/

GitHub officials response is that they are thinking about a non-conditional re-run of an action but nothing confirmed yet. You can follow the conversation in the Github community here on any updates: https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Is-it-possible-to-manually-force-an-action-workflow-to-be-re-run/td-p/25336