# GitLab pipelines equivalent for GitHub actions

Tags: gitlab-ci, github-actions

I have a pipeline in GitLab that consists of multiple stages.
Each stage has a few jobs and produces artifacts, that are passed to the next stage if all the jobs from a stage will pass.

Something similar to this screenshot:
[image: gitlab pipeline]

Is there any way to achieve something similar in GitHub actions?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205410/gitlab-ci-specify-that-job-c-should-run-after-job-b-if-job-a-fails?rq=1

Comment: @attin83 - I already have a GitLab pipeline like that. Now I want to have something similar in GitHub actions.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can get very close to what you have above in GitHub actions. You'd trigger a workflow based on `push` and `pull_request` events so that it triggers when someone pushes to your repository, then you'd define each of your jobs. You would then use the `needs` syntax to define dependencies instead of stages (which is similar to the 14.2 `needs` syntax from GitLab), so for example your `auto-deploy` job would have `needs: [test1, test2]`.

The one thing you will not be able to replicate is the manual wait on pushing to production. GitHub actions does not have the ability to pause at a job step and wait for a manual action. You can typically work around this by running workflows based on the `release` event, or by using a manual kick-off of the whole pipeline with a given variable set.

When looking at how to handle artifacts, check out the answer in this other stack overflow question: [Github actions share workspace/artifacts between jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498605/github-actions-share-workspace-artifacts-between-jobs)

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP is 2 years old , but you can so far only use environment based manual triggers (approver based security rule) as shown below.
github sucks big time just because of this missing feature

```
ManualApprove:
needs: build
environment:
  name: approvers
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: manual approve
  run: |
      echo "Manualy approved"
```

source thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73708545/14744336

Note : You also have community G-action that pauses a workflow but will take an issue at each run (equally sucks if you come from Gitlab)
[trstringer/manual-approval@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manual-workflow-approval)